# how should slow diagnostics be handled in VS Code API direct implementation

Tags: vscode-extensions, diagnostics

The diagnostics in my VS Code extension, implemented directly (no language server), are blocking other things (e.g. completions) while they run.  Furthermore, it seems, if they are triggered again before the prior analysis completes the delays are multiplied several-fold.  As a result the experience can be very unpleasant on complex workspaces.

Is there a small example of an extension that does *not* use LSP, and that handles this well, the API documentation is very light on this point, and I don't find much info by searching.  Or, can someone give a summary of a broad strategy for dealing with it.  Again, the issue is diagnostics are blocking other services for too long.

Further notes:

- In early attempts I tried simply invoking the diagnostics on every document change event, results very nice for small files, but disastrous for large ones.
- Somewhat better results by using a timer to prevent diagnostics from running in rapid succession, i.e., do not run if another run was recently started.  A run is forced on "document will save".
- Briefly toyed with putting diagnostics in an asynchronous function, seemingly no improvement, but maybe did not spend enough time working at it.  Should this be necessary? I kind of thought the API would take care of concurrent operations behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I never found an example where expensive diagnostic updates are done effectively without LSP.  So I ended up switching to LSP.  Even then how to optimize is an issue - TypeScript seems to handle it extremely well.  Some, like rust, appear to use the strategy of only updating on save.  This isn't bad, but you do end up with squiggles that get out of sync until the user hits save.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I've tried some things and they didn't improve the performance, but I found that Todo Tree is somehow interfering with my extension slowing it down by a factor of 2 to 4.